# Appropriate margin filler for responsive grid design at wider widths

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-grid

I have been ["working with one of the many frameworks or grid systems laying out sites on a 12-column flexible grid"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Realizing_common_layouts_using_CSS_Grid_Layout#A_flexible_12-column_layout) and since after months of using Bootstrap I have become neither a journeyman nor an apprentice, I'm experimenting with using just grids and media queries for laying out a site. The following code is a simplification of design offered through the nice tutorial at the URL just referenced, also using hints from Rachel Andrew's inspiring https://gridbyexample.com .

```css
.box {
    background-color: #ddd; color: #000; padding: 20px;
}
.main-head { grid-area: hd; }
.content { grid-area: ct; }
.main-nav { grid-area: nv; }
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 2px;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "nv"
        "ct";
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .wrapper {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
        grid-template-areas: 
            "nv nv"
            "ct ct";
    }
    nav ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
}        
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .wrapper {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: 
            "nv ct ct"
            "nv ct ct";
    }
    nav ul {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .wrapper {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 4fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: 
            ". nv ct ct ."
            ". nv ct ct .";
    }
    nav ul {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="box main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Nav 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nav 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nav 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <article class="box content">
        <h1>Main</h1>
    </article> 
</div>
```

The code above attempts to simulate inserting two side margins when the window exceeds some (1200) width, but using the period for padding `grid-template-area` seems like cheating. Is there a more natural way to insert these margins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `margin` as you would anywhere else, no? Of course if you want the space to the sides to be exactly 1fr it makes sense to use the the empty cell approach with `.`

```css
.box {
    background-color: #ddd; color: #000; padding: 20px;
}
.main-head { grid-area: hd; }
.content { grid-area: ct; }
.main-nav { grid-area: nv; }
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 2px;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "nv"
        "ct";
    transition: margin 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .wrapper {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
        grid-template-areas: 
            "nv nv"
            "ct ct";
    }
    nav ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
}        
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .wrapper {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: 
            "nv ct ct"
            "nv ct ct";
    }
    nav ul {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .wrapper {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: 
            "nv ct ct"
            "nv ct ct";
        margin: 0 5%;
    }
    nav ul {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="box main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Nav 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nav 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nav 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <article class="box content">
        <h1>Main</h1>
    </article> 
</div>
```

Comment: Cool. Using a percent ratio is more pleasing than a fixed px setting, but the hiccup at the boundary remains. I suppose this will have to tolerated until nonlinear ratios are an option (or are they an option already?).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "hiccup"? EDIT: Oh, you mean at the media query boundary?

Comment: Added a transition for the `margin`, so it's a bit smoother, does that go in the direction you're looking for?